# Can't get module to show up in admin/sitebuild/modules

Tags: 6

Normally all you need to do is create a modulename.info file with 
name = modulename
description = This module sends a text message every hour.
core = 6.x

Then an empty modulename.module

put both files under sites/all/modules/modulename and presto, the module should be showing up in the list under admin/sitebuilding/modules. 
I did this a couple of times checking that the core version would be correspond to the drupal version at hand, and of course doubleverifying that I working in the correct site folder. Nothing's showing.

What am I missing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is make sure you use the right program to make files for your drupal module. Or at least have your code editor configured so it creates valid files for your module.

Your custom module could be saying it's not compatible with your core drupal version due to invalid module files so that could be a bit misleading.

Answer (score 0):

> Then an empty modulename.module

The module should contain atleast

```
<?php
```

in order to show up.

Comment: adding `<?php` didn't help either. I did all sorts of things. I followed the pro drupal development from apress as well as http://drupal.org/node/206754. I had the module show up before with just that info file and the modulename.module file like I did. I really wonder what I'm not seeing.

Comment: have you cleared the cache?

Comment: yes. didn't help

Comment: Have you double checked that everything is named correctly (ie everything is declared as modulename - there are no spelling mistakes in one part that says odulename or something)?

Comment: After having had my nose glued on the content of the files and the naming of the files, the folderstructure and what have you, I realised that Drupal wouldn't accept any files I created with the mac texteditor. Using Textwrangler did the trick.

I normally use Netbeans for php and I thought texteditor would be fine for creating 'loose' files.